# Android Studio is not suggesting the keyword 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter '

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[Gradle's Screenshot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3swJ.png) Android Studio in not suggesting the keyword `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. When I tried to type it manually then it shows error. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which is apart of the Firebase-UI library but you haven't added it's dependency at all. To solve this, please add the following dependecy in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
```